# Doctrine ORM Association Mapping with two columns

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to make a one to many association from multiple entities to one.

Entity_1, Entity_2, Entity_3, Entity_... all should have a one to many to Entity_A.

But this is not possible in Doctrine:

- [Join-Columns with non-primary keys](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#join-columns-with-non-primary-keys)
- [Mapping many tables to one
  entity](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/limitations-and-known-issues.html#mapping-many-tables-to-one-entity)

Is there a workaround? What's the best way?

Comment: Check that: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html

Comment: I've read about this. But I don't see how this can be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need ManyToOne // OneToMany

But need primary keys if you don't have, you need to build custom query with joins

```
    manyToOne:
        nameforthepoint:
            targetEntity: EntityDestinyName
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null (depends bidirectional)
            joinColumns:
                name_of_the_origin_column:
                    referencedPropertyEntityName: name_of_the_destiny_column
            orphanRemoval: false
```

If you don't related by primary keys (exemple Symfony&Doctrine query with join):

```
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $db = $em->getConnection();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM  table as p1
            INNER JOIN table2 AS p2 ON p2.column = p1.column";

        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $params = array();
        $stmt->execute($params);

        $resultset = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Hope it help you, ask/comment if you need aditional info.

Comment: I already thought custom queries might be the only solution. I hoped this wouldn't be the case

Comment: I'm sorry, in the symfoyny documentation they already say:

It is not possible to use join columns pointing to non-primary keys. Doctrine will think these are the primary keys and create lazy-loading proxies with the data, which can lead to unexpected results. Doctrine can for performance reasons not validate the correctness of this settings at runtime but only through the Validate Schema command.